# admin_enqueue_scripts not working

Tags: admin, wp-enqueue-script, media-modal

#### enqueue.php

```php
function sunset_load_admin_scripts( $hook )
{
    if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_register_script('sunset-admin-script',get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/news_admin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('sunset-admin-script');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sunset_load_admin_scripts' );
```

#### news_admin.js

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("ddddddddd");

        var mediaUploader;

        jQuery('#upload_button').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(mediaUploader){
                mediaUploader.open();
                return;
            }
            mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                title: 'Choose a Image',
                button: {
                    text: 'Choose a Image'
                },
                multiple: false
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove that conditional in the first line of the enqueue function, your scripts should load. I can't see the broader context of why your function is written that way, but if you just copied it from a tutorial or something, you don't need it here.

Try:

```
<?php 
function sunset_load_admin_scripts(){ 
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_register_script('sunset-admin-script',get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/news_admin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('sunset-admin-script'); 
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sunset_load_admin_scripts' );
```

Please note admin_enqueue_scripts will only enqueue scripts for the back-end of your site, not the front-end. You can replace it with wp_enqueue_scripts if you want it to work on the frontend.